# Mutually exclusive conditionals don't work in Stata

Tags: if-statement, stata

I have some data on Stata with some variables like `logTA` and `class`. I have more than a thousand observations and `logTA` doesn't have any missing values. Data looks like this:

```
logTA       class
--------    --------
.           
.           
21.26871    
.
```

Now, what I want to do is to assign values to `class` variable according to the following simple rules:

```
replace class = 1 if logTA < mean(logTA) - sd(logTA)
replace class = 2 if logTA >= mean(logTA) - sd(logTA) & logTA < mean(logTA) + sd(logTA)
replace class = 3 if logTA >= mean(logTA) + sd(logTA)
```

It looks simple but Stata doesn't have mean() and sd() functions that can be used in this way. Anyway, I replaced mean(logTA) with 19.76543 and sd(logTA) with 1.507828.

However, among many a thousand of observations, the observation with `logTA` = 21.26871 isn't assigned any class. How this could be possible when my conditionals are mutually exclusive?

---

Here I uploaded my file: http://wikisend.com/download/187254/problem.dta
When I was trying to simplify the data set to send here, I realized that changing variable names solves the problem. So, in order to reproduce the error, just run the following code and check the last 9 rows.

```
gen sBuyuklukSinifi = .
replace sBuyuklukSinifi = 1 if logmToplamVarliklar < 19.76543 - 1.507828
replace sBuyuklukSinifi = 2 if logmToplamVarliklar >= 19.76543 - 1.507828 & logmToplamVarliklar < 19.74152 + 1.507828
replace sBuyuklukSinifi = 3 if logmToplamVarliklar >= 19.76543 + 1.507828
```

Comment: "doesn't have any nonmissing values": I think you mean missing".

Comment: thanks, I corected it.

Comment: Look carefully at the coding for the second replace statement above; a different value was substituted for the second occurrence of mean(logTA) in the if clause.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could't see it myself. I am a bit ashamed for blaming if conditinals and keeping busy some nice people. I am new at Stata and learned nice tricks by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I might accomplish this:

```
/* Fake Data */
clear
set seed 5615
set obs 100000
generate logTA = rnormal(19.76543,1.507828)
replace logTA=21.26871 in 1

summarize logTA, detail
generate class = . 
replace class = 1 if logTA < r(mean) - r(sd)
replace class = 2 if inrange(logTA,r(mean) - r(sd),r(mean) + r(sd))
replace class = 3 if logTA >= r(mean) + r(sd)
```

Results of calculations are stored by `summarize` in `r()` so that they can be easily accessed and substituted into subsequent commands, instead of typing the values.

I am not sure why your code does not work. I get the same answer as above with:

```
generate class2 = . 
replace class2 = 1 if logTA < 19.76503 - 1.513932
replace class2 = 2 if inrange(logTA,19.76503 - 1.513932,19.76503 + 1.513932)
replace class2 = 3 if logTA >= 19.76503 + 1.513932
tab class class2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing me about r(). `replace class2 = 2 if inrange(logTA,19.76503 - 1.507828,19.76503 + 1.507828)` made the necessary changes at the observation where logTA = 21.26871 at which `replace class = 2 if logTA >= 19.76503 - 1.507828 & logTA < 19.76503 + 1.507828` fails.

Comment: A point to notice is that `inrange()` includes both endpoints so it is not equivalent to `logTA >= x & logTA < y`. The last `replace` would need a `>` to make the conditions mutually exclusive. Whether this makes a difference or not, depends on the data, but shouldn't be left to luck.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dimitriy, I can't reproduce your problem and so have to regard the assertion in your title as unsubstantiated.

Here is my check, confirming also that precedence rules (which operation is evaluated first) don't bite.

```
. local a 21.26871  

. di `a' >= 19.76503 - 1.507828 & `a' < 19.76503 + 1.507828 
1

. di (`a' >= 19.76503 - 1.507828) & (`a' < 19.76503 + 1.507828) 
1
```

I note that the value in question is not sitting on the fence:

```
. di 19.76503 + 1.507828
21.272858
```

Not the issue, but `egen` has a `std()` function. You could then round results as desired, although statistically categorising is just throwing away information.